# Вырезать только нужный текст

Tags: php

Есть строка `Покупка паетов: Ntv_56°E, Xtra TV 4W на сумму 0.066667 $`

Как получить только `Ntv_56°E, Xtra TV 4W` , учитывая что строка может быть и такой: `Покупка паетов: Ntv_56°E на сумму 0.066667 $`

Буду благодарен за помощь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нужно искать символ `:`, за которым следует пробел, и далее - любая последовательность любых символов, отличных от русских букв. Для этой задачи я составил шаблон `(?<=:\s)[^а-я]+(?=\s)`, и теперь опишу его составляющие.

С помощью позитивной ретроспективной проверки `(?<= )` выполняется поиск позиции, слева от которой находится символ `:`, за которым следует пробел *(обозначены стрелками `^`)*:

```
(?<=:\s)
    ^^^
```

С помощью символьного класса `[ ]` и метасимвола `^` *(который внутри символьного класса обозначает отрицание)* выполняется поиск символов, которые не совпадают с диапазоном символов от `а` до `я` включительно. Иначе говоря, совпадения будут найдены для любых символов, кроме букв русского алфавита. Квантификатор `+` указывает на поиск одного или более таких символов. Иначе говоря, поиск будет успешным, если будет найден хотя бы один символ из перечисленных в символьном классе:

```
[^а-я]+
  ^^^
```

С помощью позитивной опережающей проверки `(?= )` выполняется поиск позиции, справа от которой находится пробел:

```
(?=\s)
   ^^
```

Следует помнить, что **опережающие проверки ищут позиции в строке**, а не соответствие символам, и поэтому результат их успешного поиска не будет "виден" в найденной подстроке. Если говорить конкретно об этом шаблоне `(?<=:\s)[^а-я]+(?=\s)`, то символ `: и следующий сразу за ним пробел`, а так же `пробел, который следует после найденного совпадения с символьным классом`, не будут включены в найденную подстроку.

```
$str = 'Покупка паетов: Ntv_56°E, Xtra TV 4W на сумму 0.066667 $';

$patt = '~(?<=:\s)[^а-я]+(?=\s)~u';
preg_match($patt, $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Ntv_56°E, Xtra TV 4W' (length=22)
```

Для строки `Покупка паетов: Ntv_56°E на сумму 0.066667 $` результат будет таким:

```
array (size=1)
  0 => string 'Ntv_56°E' (length=10)
```

Comment: то что нужно! спасибо большое.

Comment: @Денис я дополнил шаблон, чтобы не захватывать пробел в конце строки.

Comment: @Эдуард пожалуйста, распишите что делает данная регулярка, не все шарят в них, я, в частности, тоже. Убирает все кириллические буквы?

Comment: @DaemonHK отредактировал свой ответ.

Comment: @DaemonHK на счёт вашего вопроса `Убирает все кириллические буквы?` - preg_match() ищет совпадения с шаблоном, и в случае успеха возвращает результат. Если результат не нужен, а нужно удаление, то для этих целей есть preg_replace().

Comment: @Эдуард эх, была бы возможность поставить еще один плюс этому ответу)) Большое спасибо!